# How to deal with a second window

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got an experience in designing websites with ASP.Net MVC.

I want now to be able to deal with WPF. So, I'm developping a tiny App to learn a few topics like threading, filestreams, and so on.

But, my problem seems really basic :

I've got on my main window a button that fires an action which calls another window. The new windows'aim is to get 2 strings and 2 doubles, to send them back to the main window.

My problem is, that the main window is not launched that way :

```
MainWindow m = new mainwindow;
```

And I'd like to do something like :

```
m.someVariable = somethingFromMySecondWindow.
```

So, I've tryed to set the main window static, but I got lots of errors, so I removed the "static".
I can't access variables from my second window, or any public method.

I don't know if it is needed, but here is the c# code i've already written.

mainWindow :

```
namespace FlightPlanningDraft1
{
/// <summary>
/// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string _ACModel;
    private string _ACIdentification;
    private double _ACFuelConsumption;
    private double _ACTotalFuel;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChargementAvion c = new ChargementAvion();
        c.Show();
    }

    public void Validation_Avion(string aCModel,string aCIdentification, double aCFuelConsumption, double aCTotalFuel)
    {
        _ACModel = aCModel;
        _ACIdentification = aCIdentification;
        _ACFuelConsumption = aCFuelConsumption;
        _ACTotalFuel = aCTotalFuel;
    }

}
}
```

My second window

```
namespace FlightPlanningDraft1
{
/// <summary>
/// Logique d'interaction pour ChargementAvion.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ChargementAvion : Window
{

    public ChargementAvion()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //I don't know what to do here.
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event to the second windows. Subscribe on it inside `MenuItem_Click` (`MainWindow`), and fire that event from Second window (`Button_Click`).

You can pass any value to you event.

```
public partial class ChargementAvion :Window
{
   public event Action<string> OnDone;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(OnDone != null)
        { 
           OnDone("any string you want to pass");
        }
    }
}
```

and in MainWindow:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChargementAvion c = new ChargementAvion();
        c.OnDone += ResultsHandler;
        c.Show();
    }

  public void ResultsHandler(string result)
  {
     //do what you want ;)
  }
```

---

I'd suggest you to look through [this article](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html). Just to be more familiar with events and delegates in C#.

Comment: So, do you mean using something like that? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd990377.aspx
If so, it was the next thing I was willing to study

Comment: I updated my answer. You shold use events. And you can use any other class instead of string. That's just an example.

Comment: awsomely sumerized ;-)
I needed exactly such an example, thank you ;-)